# How to extract an argument of 'function' type from NSInvocation

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock, nsinvocation

I am writing a unit test for the function that receives a protocol as input argument.
This function that I am testing calls some method of that protocol inside.
I want to mock this protocol and that method.
To mock the protocol using OCMock I wrote the following:
`id<MyProtocol> myProtocol = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(MyProtocol));`

Now to mock the function I am using OCMStub.
The interesting part is that the function doesn't return any value but rather gets the callback as input argument and invokes it.
Here is its signature:
`- (void)myFunction:(void (^ _Nonnull)(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> * _Nonnull))completion;`

I am writing the following code to mock this function:
`OCMStub([myProtocol myFunction:[OCMArg any]])._andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation){
        void (^ _Nonnull)(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> * _Nonnull) completion;
        [invocation getArgument:&completion atIndex:0];
        // Here I will invoke the completion callback with some dictionary and invoke the invocation
    });`

However I am getting the following error: "`Expected identifer or '('`". The error points to the line that defines `completion` variable.

**How can I define the function variable of signature `void (^ _Nonnull)(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> * _Nonnull)`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was able to extract a first argument by doing the following:
    `OCMStub([myProtocol myFunction:[OCMArg any]])._andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation){
        void (^ completion)(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> * _Nonnull);
        [invocation getArgument:&completion atIndex:2];
        // Do other stuff
    });`

I was just declaring a variable of 'block' type incorrectly.
And I have also realized that the first argument should be accessed by index = 2;

Answer (score 1):

That ain't a function.  It is a block!

Regardless, both functions and blocks can be treated as `void *` in declarations.  You'll need to cast them to the appropriate type after.

But that's probably the easiest way to deal with it;  extract from the invocation as a `void*`, cast to a block, call it.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also add an example of how to cast to a block?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that it is named 'block'! I have learned how to create variables of 'block' type and it solved the problem. There is no need to declare `void *` variable and casting it to a block. As the address of the variable of a block type can be passed directly to `[NSInvocation getArgument]`